# Common, inherited layout for non-resource routes in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, routes

I have some sections of my app that share a common layout. These are non-resource URLs like:

```
/about
/signup
... and more
```

I'm trying to share a base template between these routes *that differs from my main application template*. Most of the app lives under `/products` therefore the `products.hbs` template serves as a base template there.

I have working... I'm just not sure if it follows Ember conventions or if it's the best way to tackle it. Basically, I have an empty application template (just an outlet) and then a custom route to be inherited (`routes/public-route.js`) that loads up a shared template.

Here's what I have:

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}
```

**templates/layout/public.hbs**

```
// this is the shared base template for routes not under `/products`
<div class="public">
  <h1>Share base template</h1>
  {{#link-to 'signup'}}Signup{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

**templates/products.hbs**

```
<div class="splitview">
  <h1>Default app view</h1>
  {{#link-to 'products'}}Products{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'products.featured'}}Featured{{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
</div
```

**routes/public-route.js**

```
App.PublicRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('layout/public');
    this.render({ into: 'layout/public' });
  }
});
```

**routes/about.js**

```
App.AboutRoute = PublicRoute.extend();
```

**routes/signup.js**

```
App.SignupRoute = PublicRoute.extend();
```

**router.js**

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend();
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.resource('featured', { path: '/featured' }, function() {});
  });
  this.route('about');
  this.route('signup');
});
```

This seems to work. I can transition to `signup` or `about` and the their templates are rendered inside the `layout/public.hbs` outlet. Is it bad practice to have your `application.hbs` be just an outlet? Are there better approaches to this? It seems like this would be a common scenario...